# Why does pdfkit redacts texts of a different language while converting a webpage to pdf?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pdfkit

Here is my code:

```py
import requests
import pdfkit as pk
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def save_PDF(url):
 html = session.get(url)
 soup = bs(html.content, 'html.parser')
 title=str(soup.find('title').string)
 if " (" in title:
  title=title.split(' (')[0]
 else:
  title=title.split(' |')[0]
 print("Saving "+title)
 htmlTitle=title+".html"
 pdf=open(htmlTitle,'wb+')
 pdf.write(html.content)
 pdf.close()
 pdfTitle=title+".pdf"
 pk.from_file(htmlTitle,pdfTitle)
```

Here is the output:
[image: PDF Demo]
Lines under those black boxes are written in **Bengali**.
How do I fix this issue?
Are there any alternatives?

Comment: You are likely not exposing a font that has Bengali characters to the PDF processor.

Comment: How do I fix this? @KevinBrown

Comment: Perhaps review this ... https://github.com/dibosh/bangla-pdf/tree/master/fonts

Comment: Any idea how to define multiple fonts for both Bengali and English for a number of HTML files?

Comment: Normally one would use font-family with a comma separated list of fonts.